# Connect PowerBI IOS app to Reporting Services

Tags: ios, sql-server, reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-mobile

I am trying to connect my PowerBI IOS app to Reporting Services 2016 (13.0.1601.5) using [documentation](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-mobile-iphone-kpis-mobile-reports/).

During connection I get:

> **Server address not valid.** 
>   A server with the specified hostname could
>   not be find. Make sure you're using a SQL Server 2016 Reporting
>   Services server adress, e.g., https://server_address/reports or
>   http://server_address/reports.

using working address in SQL Server Mobile Report Publisher (I can connect to dataset).

rsreportserver file contains:

```
<Authentication>
        <AuthenticationTypes>
            <RSWindowsNTLM/>
        </AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Off</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
        <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>Proxy</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>
        <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```

Comment: Pretty sure I had this error once. I think I got around it by inserting the IP of the server.

Comment: I've checked [IP4]/reports. On my server ask me about credentials (works), on my local computer I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT and on mobile I get The request timed out...

Comment: Have you checked the firewall isn't causing a problem

Comment: I've just added [TCP access to 1433 & 1434] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-windows-firewall-for-database-engine-access), without any results.